# Leave only the Server and Client files in a mysql installed manually on windows

Tags: mysql, windows-7, installation, disk-space-utilization, manual

I am a php developer and I'm setting up a portable development environment on windows 7.

I downloaded the version of mysql "NonInstall Zip Archive" and is working properly.

However, I see that occupies over 1GB in size !!

I imagine that to run and test my web projects developed in php, I just need the MySQL server and maybe (not sure) also MySQL client.

What files can I delete to free up space?

I know that if I had used the Windows MSI Installer, would have the MySQL Installer GUI tool to delete unnecessary files. Can I do it manually without having to install this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the files and folders I deleted:

**bin** folder: All ***.pdb** files
**docs** folder
**include** folder
**lib** folder
**mysql-test** folder
**share** folder: Removed **languages folders** except english and spanish.
**share\charsets** folder
**sql-bench** folder

A month later using mysql, I have not had any problems.